# Ubuntu web server can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, server

I have ubuntu server installed using virtualbox with LAMP, OpenSSH, and mail. When I do an ifconfig I get an ipaddress, but when I go to my host machine and put it in, it can't connect to the server.

I have my VM Network as:
Bridge Adapter
using my wireless network card

When I start the machine for bridge adapter it just sits and shows:
A start job is running for Raised network interfaces (50s / 5min 5s).

Answer (score 0):

I had this yesterday and it was all due to a mis-configuration in my "/etc/network/interfaces" file.  Make sure you are using the **actual** NIC/Wireless names (type "ip link" in a terminal to find them) to make the bridge and not eth0 / eth1 unless you've made the necessary changes to call them that make and make sure you have the necessary gateway/broadcast etc. in the same file if using static rather than DHCP.

Also, comment out any line in reference to your current NIC/Wireless (add a # to the beginning of the line(s)) as you should only set the IP on the bridge and not the NIC/Wireless directly.

I'm still new to the Ubuntu and Networking but this was what I learned yesterday whilst trying to add a router function to my (dedicated) server.

Good luck and please let me know if this works or not - I don't like to give unreliable feedback / help.